# Executing Mozart-Oz code in command line

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm trying to use [Mozart Oz](https://github.com/mozart/mozart2). 
I download the execution binary from source forge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozart-oz/.

When launching Mozart.app, the emacs (aquamacs for Mac OS X) starts to do the coding within it.

For example, I can type in `{Browse 'Hello World'}` and execute `Oz  -> Feed Buffer` to get the result in Tcl/Tk browser.

Then, how can I build or execute the Oz code in command line just like I do with Python or Ruby?

I found binaries in the bin directory.

```
/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin
    ├── oz
    ├── ozc
    ├── ozemulator
    ├── ozengine
    └── ozwish
```

However, when I execute the code with `ozc -c hello.oz`, I got `%** variable Browse not introduced` error. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use `Browser.browse`

Actually, every function must be imported/created when building application in oz. When you import Browser, you get a record with all the functions that the Browser object class export. (see https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/browser/node2.html)

thus, your code is

```
functor
import
   Browser
define
   {Browser.browse 'Hello World'}
end
```

I should exit the application with {Application.exit 0} but it gives me a weird error...
Anyway, I recommend not to use the Browser. Even if it's very powerful when using an interactive interpreter, it's heavy and buggy. Use System.showInfo instead, and build your own TK window if you really want one.

```
functor
import
    System
    Application
define
    {System.showInfo 'Hello World!'}
    {Application.exit 0}
end
```

you compile it with

```
$ ozc -c hello.oz
```

and then run it with

```
$ ozengine hello.ozf
```